# [cordova, ionic]Android fullscreen display empty place error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

i'm korean..
i am not goot at english

My question 
- I want to always show the status bar in full screen.And transparent
Android fullscreen space error 
error video link
 https://youtu.be/y53L9CQjAIY

app.js

> angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers',
>   'starter.services','starter.directives','ngCordova'])
>
> .run(function($ionicPlatform,$window,$cordovaStatusbar) {
>   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
>
> ```
> if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
>   cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
>   cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
> }
> if (window.StatusBar) {
>  StatusBar.styleDefault();
> $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true);
>   $cordovaStatusbar.show();
>   statusbarTransparent.enable();
>
> }   }); })
> ```

Please help me ..